# selective dimming of html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im creating a submenu. The idea is that when the submenu is open, the brightness of the HTML reduces. Im reducing the opacity to achieve this. The problem with my code is that it is reducing the opacity of the entire HTML, including the submenu. I tried to include provisions for this in my javascript but its not working. I am attaching my code below. How do I solve this and what are other methods to reduce the brightness of the webpage?

```js
const USERINFO = document.getElementById("USERINFO");
const subMenu = document.getElementById("login-subMenu");
const html = document.documentElement;

USERINFO.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "0";
  html.classList.add("dimmed");
});

html.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target !== USERINFO && !subMenu.contains(event.target)) {
    subMenu.style.right = "-400px";
    html.classList.remove("dimmed");
  }
});

const closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "-400px";
  html.classList.remove("dimmed");
});
```

```css
#login-subMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -400px;
  /* Hide the menu offscreen to start */
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.dimmed {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <a id="USERINFO">My Account</a>
</div>
<div id="login-subMenu">
  <button id="closeButton">Close X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `filter: brightness(70%)`

Comment: hey, i tried this but it has the same problem as opacity. This there any other syntax I can use? Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: You cannot target the documentElement (HTML), set the opacity and exclude inner children from getting the CSS applied to them. You have to create a container element (e.g. a div) that will contain all the code that needs to be dimmed, while the submenu will be outside this container div.

Comment: You can fake it by putting a full-screen, partly transparent, white `<div>` behind the submenu. Then the submenu can remain in a sensible place in the DOM and doesn't have to be pulled out to the top level.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `documentElement` will apply the opacity to all the elements included within the HTML document. You cannot exclude the submenu, as it's a child of HTML.

You just have to use another "container" for the dimmed part of the HTML.

```js
const USERINFO = document.getElementById("USERINFO");
const subMenu = document.getElementById("login-subMenu");
const container = document.querySelector("#container");

USERINFO.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "0";
  container.classList.add("dimmed");
});

container.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target !== USERINFO && !subMenu.contains(event.target)) {
    subMenu.style.right = "-400px";
    container.classList.remove("dimmed");
  }
});

const closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  subMenu.style.right = "-400px";
  container.classList.remove("dimmed");
});
```

```css
#login-subMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -400px;
  /* Hide the menu offscreen to start */
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.dimmed {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="info">
    <a id="USERINFO">My Account</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="login-subMenu">
  <button id="closeButton">Close X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @kostas, thanks for the help. I find a problem with your code. As per your code, only the brightness of #USERINFO is reducing. Maybe I didn't make it clear but #USERINFO is just element part of my navbar.  There are other elements like a sub-menu, logo, etc. Further, the webpage has a mast, other divs and footer that make the body of the webpage. Can you help me with how I can reduce the brightness of all these elements when #USERINFO is clicked?

Comment: Just wrap all these elements in the #container div @ThorThedog

Comment: Wont it hamper the performance if header, footer, etc are all wrapper in one div?

Comment: Nope. Or at least, not at a point that you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- Prefer `<dialog>` over custom implementations.
- Your issue:

  - Reducing `opacity` of an element also applies to all its children.
  - Take inspiration from `<dialog>`; namely its top layer mechanism.

## Regarding your code

`opacity` literally changes the opacity, and does *not* dim. The background of elements with `opacity` below 1 will be visible:

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => main.classList.toggle("dimmed"));
```

```css
.dimmed {opacity: .25}

main {background-color: white}

/*Make main cover viewport*/
html {height: 100%}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 1fr / 1fr;
}

/*Add below content*/
html {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1280/720);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Some paragraph that will be "dimmed", but actually translucent.</p>
  <button>Toggle dimming</button>
</main>
```

So you may want to choose [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) (e.g. with `brightness()`) for dimming instead:

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", () => main.classList.toggle("dimmed"));
```

```css
.dimmed {filter: brightness(.25)}

main {background-color: white}

/*Make main cover viewport*/
html {height: 100%}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 1fr / 1fr;
}

/*Add below content*/
html {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1280/720);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>Some paragraph that will be dimmed.</p>
  <button>Toggle dimming</button>
</main>
```

But both `opacity` and `filter` of an element also apply to all its children. This includes children with `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`, and even `<dialog>` elements.

## Prefer `<dialog>`

For dialogs you should prefer the [`<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog). Opening it via [`HTMLDialogElement.showModal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal) automatically dims the background and traps focus inside:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");

const buttonOpen = document.getElementById("open");
const buttonOpenAsModal = document.getElementById("open-as-modal");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.show());
buttonOpenAsModal.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.showModal());
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph outside a dialog.</p>
<button id="open">Open dialog</button>
<button id="open-as-modal">Open dialog as modal</button>

<dialog>
  <form method=dialog>
    <button aria-label="Close">&Cross;</button>
  </form>
  <p>A paragraph in a dialog.</p>
</dialog>
```

A modal dialog is displayed in a so-called [*top layer*](https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#top-layer). That layer is effectively the last child of `<body>` with the highest [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index), ensuring it to be above all other elements.

A modal dialog also creates a [`::backdrop` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop) that dims the background, i.e. all other elements.

### Custom dialog

For a custom dialog implementation we can take inspiration from `<dialog>`, its `::backdrop` and the top layer.

Placing the dialogs at the end of `<body>` with the highest z-index keep them top-most:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("[role=dialog]");

const buttonOpen = document.getElementById("open");
const buttonClose = document.getElementById("close");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.classList.add("open"));
buttonClose.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.classList.remove("open"));
```

```css
[role=dialog] {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
}
[role=dialog]:not(.open) {display: none}

/*Presentational styling*/
[role=dialog] {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .8rem;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph outside the custom dialog.</p>
<button id="open">Open dialog</button>

<div role=dialog>
  <button id="close" aria-label="Close">&Cross;</button>
  <p>A paragraph inside our custom dialog.</p>
</div>
```

Using a mock top layer allows for blocking clicks and dimming of the background:

```js
const dialog = document.querySelector("[role=dialog]");

const buttonOpen = document.getElementById("open");
const buttonClose = document.getElementById("close");

buttonOpen.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.classList.add("open"));
buttonClose.addEventListener("click", () => dialog.classList.remove("open"));
```

```css
#top-layer:has([role=dialog].open)::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

/*Same as before*/
[role=dialog] {
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: .8rem;
  max-width: 90vw;
  max-height: 90vh;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: white;
}
[role=dialog]:not(.open) {display: none}
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph outside the custom dialog.</p>
<button id="open">Open dialog</button>

<div id="top-layer">
  <div role=dialog>
    <button id="close" aria-label="Close">&Cross;</button>
    <p>A paragraph inside our custom dialog.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: This does not trap focus inside the dialog.